# Post something on the wall of facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, eclipse

I want to post a message on facebook wall post. I am using this code. If i use

`.setType(image/jpeg)` it attaches the image and works fine. However I can't get it work with message. Kindly tell me how can i Fix this

```
String msg = "My Message" ;
            Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MainMenu.this)
                      .setType("text/plain")
                      .setText(msg)
                      .getIntent()
                      .setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
            try{
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Sorry, but it seems that application is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below links here you will have some information

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

this may help you

Comment: It won't i dont want to use api :(